# How to do multivariate analysis on data not normally distributed?

Tags: parametric, variance, covariance, data-analysis

I have a series of continuous measurements that are not normally distributed (multivariate Shapiro-Wilk test p-value = 0.003818, Anderson-Darling test p-value = 0.0178 or lower for each variable) that are then stratified by several other ordinal data (such as: death Y/N, sex M/F, fever Y/N).

I understand that multivariate analysis can be done only with normally distributed data. The question is: are there not-normal alternatives? As there is the Mann–Whitney U test for the t-test, is there a non-parametric MANOVA?

Alternatively, what would be the procedure to analyze not normally distributed data?

Comment: _How_ to do it depends on what hypotheses you want to test, but "multivariate analysis can be done only with normally distributed data" is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Kruskal-Wallis test can be used. It is the equivalent of MANOVA in non-parametric tests.